# Django validator to correct rather than reject user input

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

In my elicitation app (started as the polls tutorial, now much larger) I am implementing my own simple hashtags for text answers.  The implementation is quite minimal, and really just uses a word-search filter based on a query-string of the word that has been tagged. The problem is that a lot of characters that are valid in an text field are not acceptable in a URL, so hashtags made by non-expert users need to be amended to work correctly.  People want to hyphenate or & ampersand their words, and it doesn't work. It also would be annoying if some people are #brain-storming and others are #brainstorming.

- What are the risks of creating a pseudo-validator that strips query-string breaking chars from user entries, but does not create validation errors?  I'm working on my own at present, but do see this as a product other people will work on or fork in the future.
- If I create a validator for this task is it more appropriate to 'validate' and amend as part of a ModelForm field, or in the models?  (Everything is a django form in this app).
- Is this already in core django somewhere?  (I'm not looking to drop in a Django hashtags app to solve this small problem, but there's a lot of Django I still need to learn)

> ```
> URL_BREAKER_TRANS = str.maketrans(dict((k, '') for k in [
>     '#', '!', '@', '$', '%', '^',
>     '&', '*', '(', ')', '+',
>     '=', ',', '.', '<', '>',
>     '?', '/', '|', '~', '[',
>     ']', '{', '}', '-', '_',
>     '`']))
> ```

```
def validate_hashtag(string1):
    """this function takes a string input, checks for hashtags and
    removes any url-breaking characters.
    Although string.translate is very fast, splitting and then looping
    word by word means this function will be demanding.
    """
    string_list = string1.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(string_list)):
        if string_list[i].startswith("#"):
            string_list[i] = "#" + string_list[i].translate(URL_BREAKER_TRANS)
        else:
            continue
    return " ".join(string_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, in writing the question I thought it through and the first thing I tried has worked well, so don't feel obliged to respond.

My solution is creating a custom form CharField subclass that subclasses 'clean' with this additional step.

Each text field in each form for each model is now a TextInputField, which is some repetition of myself that may be redundant.  Still a little concerned that its bad practice somehow to silently fix things for the user after they hit submit.

```
class TextInputField(forms.CharField):

def clean(self, value):
    super(TextInputField, self).clean(value)
    return validate_hashtag(value)
```

Comment: Not django, but you could add some javascript to communicate with the user, not accepting x character for example, and issuing a message.